# How to update react component when imported function component is finished

Tags: reactjs

How can you update a component once a function is done in another function component?

So for example with the following code:

**myFunctionComponent.tsx**

```js
class myFunctionComponent extends React.Component {

    public doSomething = () => {
        console.log('something is done');
    }
}
```

**Page.tsx**

```js
class Page extends React.Component {

    import myFunctionComponent = './myFunctionComponent.ts' 

    public componentDidMount() {
        // somehow once this is done
        myFunctionComponent.doSomething();
    }

    public render() {

        // it should update this
        const doSomethingIsDone = false;

        if (doSomethingIsDone) {
            return (<Redirect to="/" />)
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow I would like to notify Page.tsx that the doSomething in myFunctionComponent.ts is done. Should this done via a callback function somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in React, you never interact with components outside of the render function. The only way a component interacts directly with other components is by rendering them.
For the most part, there are a couple of option how to achieve them.
If you are able to render `myFunctionComponent` from inside `Page`, you can pass a callback that will fire once `doSomething` is finished.

```
export class Page extends React.Component {
  onSomething = () => { 
    // Here you can do what ever you need after `something` happens
   }

  public render() {
    return <MyFunctionComponent onSomething={this.onSomething} />
  }
}
```

The second option you have, is to extract `doSomething` to a separate file, import it and use it as a sort of service-like function:

```
import doSomething from "./do-something";

export class Page extends React.Component {
  onSomething = () => { 
    // Here you can do what ever you need after `something` happens
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     doSomething();
     doSomethingElse();
   }

  public render() {
    const doSomethingIsDone = false;

    if (doSomethingIsDone) {
      return (<Redirect to="/" />)
    }
  }
}
```

You third option is to use some form of state container ([React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) for example). This option is probably the most verbose one, and offers the most feature (depending on the state library you choose), but you may not need it.

I also recommend reading React's guide to [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), as I think it contains a lot of useful information that might answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**myFunctionComponent.tsx**

```
class myFunctionComponent extends React.Component {

    public doSomething = (callback) => {
        console.log('something is done');

        callback();
    }
}
```

**Page.tsx**

```
class Page extends React.Component {

    import myFunctionComponent = './myFunctionComponent.ts' 

    public componentDidMount() {
        // somehow once this is done
        myFunctionComponent.doSomething(this.callback);
    }

    public callback() {
        //Do something finished, refresh component
    }

    public render() {

        // it should update this
        const doSomethingIsDone = false;

        if (doSomethingIsDone) {
            return (<Redirect to="/" />)
        }
    }
}
```