# React share error message from grand-child to grand-parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can a message from a fetch in a grand-child component be provided to a grand-parent component?

I have seen the example of lifting state as described [in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). But that example and a lot of other examples for that matter have the use case where a user interacts with a button.

Also some sources ([source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582748/how-to-update-react-component-when-imported-function-component-is-finished)) show that Redux can be used. But for my application it feels as an overkill.

It seems that the state should be moved to the highest component, in this case the grandparent.

So for example with the following code:

```
class Page extends React.Component {

  state = {
    error: false;
  }

  public render() {
    const { error } = this.state;

    return(
      {!error && <Child><p>All is well!</p></Child>}
      {error && 
         <p>This message should show only when grandchild has a problem and show the message from the GrandChild.</p>
      }
    )
  }
}


class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <GrandChild><p>Here in my app the result of the grandchild is used via context. But unrelated to this question.</p></GrandChild>
    )
  }
}


class GrandChild extends React.Component {

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchClasses('http://myurl.com/api/v1/')
  }

  public fetchClasses(url) {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => {
        if(res.status === 401) {
          // error message that should be passed to my grandparent
          this.setState({error: true, loading: false});
        }
        return res.json();
      }).then(resJson => {
        // phew! everything went well, nothing to worry about
        this.setState({error: false, loading: false})
      }).catch({
        // also a more generic error message my grandparent should know about
        this.setState({error: true, loading: false})
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { error, loading } = this.state;

    return (
      {loading && <p>Please tell my grandparent to wait.</p>}
      {error && <p>Please tell my grandparent something' wrong.</p>}
      {!error && !loading && <p>My grand parent does not have to know</p>}
    )
  }
}
```

What would be a solution to pass state and information up?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make it works is by using Redux. Then you can connect all the components you need to the reducer state.

[Redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Comment: That should work. But seems like an overkill. This article explains it well: https://daveceddia.com/context-api-vs-redux/ I am currently investigating the Context API.